# How to select the first row from a ListView in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I tried this, but it's not working. `ListViewParcels` is my ListView name.

```
ListViewParcels.ListItems(1).Checked = True
```

Comment: *but it's not working* You get an error or what? [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Not getting any Error. But First row remains unselected. @Masoud

Comment: Me.ListView1.ListItems(1).Selected = True

Comment: Not Working @JohnMuggins, Anyway thank You

Comment: did you change listview1 to the name of your listview?  ie, ListViewParcels.ListItems(1).Selected = True

Comment: Yes, i changed it

Comment: That works for me.  But mine is named ListView1.  Is this listview in a form or on a worksheet?

Comment: its in  the form